# How to host a tftp server using GNU utftpd

Tags: gnu, tftp

How does one host a tftp server through GNU utftpd (https://github.com/tar-mirror/utftpd/tree/master)?

For further context, I aim to use it to upload all content from a directory e.g. ~/tftp_server through a usb-ethernet adaptor with a set ip to a recipient machine (see: https://github.com/enjoy-digital/litex).

I appreciate the novelty of this question but would still heavily value anyones insight on the matter :^)